# VB .NET Socket Programing

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a tools build in VB .Net and use Socket Programing. If just use 1 Server my code already work but when I wanna user 2 server and connect from 1 server my tools can't be handle that problem.

I wanna 1 Client can connect to 2 server

My code like this

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports Pabertiyan
Public Class Form1
Dim Client As TcpClient
Dim Client2 As TcpClient
Dim sWrinteras As StreamWriter
'Dim NickFrefix As Integer = New Random().Next(1111, 9999)
Dim Pabertiyan As New Pabertiyan.Pabertiyan

Delegate Sub _xUpdate(ByVal str As String)

Sub xUpdate(ByVal str As String)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New _xUpdate(AddressOf xUpdate), str)
    Else
        MsgBox("Sum of word in server is : " & str)
        'TextBox1.AppendText(str & vbNewLine)
    End If
End Sub

Sub Read(ByVal str As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        xUpdate(New StreamReader(Client.GetStream).ReadLine)
        Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        xUpdate("Disconnect From Server")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Send(ByVal str As String)
    Try
        sWrinteras = New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream)
        sWrinteras.WriteLine(str)
        sWrinteras.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You not Connect to Server")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Text = "Connect" Then
        Try
            Client = New TcpClient(Pabertiyan.GetIPServer, Pabertiyan.GetPortServer)
            Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Read), Nothing)
            Button1.Text = "Disconnect"
            TextBox3.BackColor = Color.Lime
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Server is Offline. Please Try Again Later!!!")
        End Try
    Else
        Client.Client.Close()
        Client = Nothing
        Button1.Text = "Connect"
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Send(TextBox5.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckConfig_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckConfig.Tick
    If Pabertiyan.ReloadConfig = 1 Then
        Button4.Enabled = True
        TextBox6.Text = Pabertiyan.ReloadConfig
    End If
    If Pabertiyan.ReloadConfig = 0 Then
        Button4.Enabled = False
        TextBox6.Text = Pabertiyan.ReloadConfig
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox5.Text = Pabertiyan.SearchChar
    TextBox2.Text = Pabertiyan.TotalServer
    TextBox7.Text = Pabertiyan.ModuleLogs
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox7.Text = Pabertiyan.ReloadConfig
    TextBox5.Text = Pabertiyan.SearchChar
End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, for me it's not clear what you are asking. I appreciate _English_ is probably not your first language however _I wanna user 2 server and connect from 1 server my tools can't be handle that problem._ and _I wanna 1 Client can connect to 2 server_ just doesn't make much sense. Are you saying _you want your application to be able to connect to two `TCPClients`_? Also can you include any errors you may be getting.

Comment: Create your own class containing all those methods and variables instead, then create a new instance of the class whenever you want a new connection. If you then make a list of those classes you'll be able to have almost as many connections as you want, each having its own methods and variables.